# Ajax Not working with post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I trying to post data to another api through ajax that time ajax wouldn't work. How I check where ajax is working or not.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#exam_id").change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "") {

        } else {

            load_subject($(this).val());
        }
    });

});
```

function load_subject(id) {

```
var post_data = {"exam_id": id};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url + "Chapter/get_subject_list",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: post_data,
        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {

            load_subject_res(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Start with your browser's JavaScript console (typically by hitting F12 on Windows). Also, add an error handler to your `$.ajax` options, eg `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.error(textStatus, errorThrown) }`

Comment: What issue are you getting right now?

Comment: Given you've said _"to **another** api"_, I'm going to guess this is a CORS issue but will wait till you confirm what your console says

Comment: Nothing display any message .Ajax not working.

Comment: if in success then what you are getting it? can you please do console.log(data);

Comment: _"Nothing display any message .Ajax not working"_ <- **exactly how** is it _"not working"_? Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: I do that but nothing return any kind of response.

Comment: Are you even looking in your browser's console? What code calls `load_subject(exam_id)`? Are you even calling it at all?

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments. [Edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49104589/edit)

Comment: This is my actual code

Comment: Just update my code.

Comment: Unable to enter inside a $.ajax